# Debugging the application while running UI tests

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

So I start an UI test in XCode, during which the an error occurs or some exeption is thrown.

I start debugging and trying to understand what the problem is, but then the UI test fails after some time out with this error message:

`Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failed to perform AX action for monitoring the animations of <XCUIApplicationProcess...`

The stack is gone and so is everything that was printed to the console. So I am unable to continue debugging after that happens.

I assume that XCode thinks it is waiting for an animation? Has anybody else this problem? Do you have an idea how to solve it? Or is there a possibility to increase the timer to more than just a few seconds?

Answer (score 8):

To stop the test failing you can pause the program execution from debug area at the bottom of Xcode and then you can switch to Application target from UI Test target (By Choosing the stack frame) and debug for as much time as you want. Just resume the execution once you want to start the test execution again.